# Something like Mojolicious for PHP?

Tags: php, perl, web-frameworks, mojolicious

Mojolicious is a very good web framework for Perl. Does anyone perhaps know if there is something similar to it for PHP?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) to write small web apps in PHP.

Snippet from docs:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```